# Laravel validator 'in' issue for numbers in input

Tags: php, regex, laravel, preg-match

I need help in fixing an issue in which I am using laravel 'in' validator to match a given input against multiple comma separated string of values. Now the issue is when there is a number in the input and it does not matches with any of the comma separated values then it gives an exception:

```
preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

However it should simply give error message in validator object that input field does not match. instead it gives above mentioned exception. Following is my code:

```
 if (!empty($program)) {
            $institution_id = $program->InstitutionId;
            $roster_users = $program->usersRosters()->where('ProfileType', 'Student')->get();
            if (!empty($roster_users)) {
                $rostered_users_ids = implode(',', $roster_users->lists('id'));
            }
            if (!empty($roster_users)) {
                $rostered_users_usernames = implode(',', $roster_users->lists('UserName'));
            }
            $teacher_roster_users = $program->usersRosters()->where('ProfileType', 'External Staff')->get();
            if (!empty($teacher_roster_users)) {
                $teacher_rostered_users_usernames = implode(',', $teacher_roster_users->lists('UserName'));
            }
            if (!empty($teacher_roster_users)) {
                $teacher_rostered_users_data = $teacher_roster_users->lists('id', 'UserName');
            }
        }
        $rules = [
            'aasectionname.required' => '501 – AA section does not exist',
            'aaid' => 'numeric|exists:users,id|in:' . $rostered_users_ids . '|aaidinstitutionmismatch:' . $institution_id,
            'institutionid' => 'numeric|in:' . $institution_id,
            'username' => 'exists:users,UserName|in:' . $rostered_users_usernames . '|usernameinstitutionmismatch:' . $institution_id,
            'schoolid' => 'numeric',
            'groupowner' => 'in:'.$teacher_rostered_users_usernames,
            'remove' => 'in:0,1'
        ];
        $messages = [
            // InstitutionId
            'institutionid.numeric' => '101 – Invalid Institution ID',
            'institutionid.in' => '102 – Institution ID does not match Program',
            // Usernames
            'username.exists' => '201 – UserName does not exist',
            'username.in' => '202 – UserName is not rostered to this program',
            'username.usernameinstitutionmismatch' => '203 – User/Institution Mismatch - UserName is not assigned to this Institution',
            // AAId
            'aaid.numeric' => '301 – AA ID does not exist',
            'aaid.exists' => '301 – AA ID does not exist',
            'aaid.in' => '302 – AA ID is not rostered to this program',
            'aaid.aaidinstitutionmismatch' => '303 – AA ID/Institution Mismatch – AAID is not assigned to this Institution',
            // Mismatch
            'bothmismatch' => '401 – AAID/UserName/SchoolID do not match (This is a combination of at least 2 of these items)',
            // Teacher
            'groupowner.in' => '501 – GroupOwner does not exist',
            // Remove
            'remove' => '601 – No Student record match to remove',
        ];

 Excel::load($file, function($excel) use($program, $rules, $messages, $errors, &$errors_data, $teacher_rostered_users_data) {
            global $totalmismatch;
            $results = $excel->get();
            $program_group_model = new ProgramGroup;
            $option_model = new Option;
            $group_default_status_id = key($option_model->getProgramsStatus(['Active']));
            $groupVisibilityStatusId = $group_type = $option_model->getVisibilityOptions('Question Visibility','Private');
            $data = [];
            $lastSecId = null;
            $groupSectionPreviousName = null;
            $groupname = null;
            $data['status'] = $group_default_status_id;
            $data['program_id'] = $program->Id;
            $groupname_lists = $program_group_model->with(['programs' => function ($query) use ($program){
                $query->where('ProgramId','=',$program->Id);
            }])->get()->lists('Name','Id');

            foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
                $inputs = $row->toArray();
                $groupname = trim($inputs['usergroup']);
                $errors = [];
                // Stop reading the excel when aasectionname is empty
                if (empty($groupname) || $groupname == null) {
                    $errors['remove'] = $messages['aasectionname.required'];
                }
                $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules, $messages);
                if ($validator->fails()) {
                    $errors = $validator->messages()->toArray();
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                        foreach ($error as $e) {
                            $errors_data[] = [$key + 2, $e];
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $aaid = intval($inputs['aaid']);
                    $groupowner_name = $inputs['groupowner'];
                    if (!empty($teacher_rostered_users_data[$groupowner_name])) {
                        $groupowner_id = $teacher_rostered_users_data[$groupowner_name];
                        $data['owner'] = $groupowner_id;
                    }
                    $remove = intval($inputs['remove']);
                    // Remove existing Student Roster
                    if (!empty($remove)) {
                        $removed = false;
                        $user_ids = is_array($aaid) ? $aaid : [$aaid];
                        $program_group = $program->programGroups()->where('Name', $groupname);
                        if (!empty($program_group)) {
                            $program_group = $program_group->first();
                        }
                        if (!empty($program_group)) {
                            $program_group = $program_group->users();
                        }
                        if (!empty($program_group) && !empty($user_ids)) {
                            $removed = $program_group->detach($user_ids);
                        }
                        if (!$removed) {
                            $errors['remove'] = $messages['remove'];
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!in_array($groupname, $groupname_lists) || $groupSectionPreviousName != $groupname)  {
                            $data['name'] = $groupname;
                            $data['group_id'] = array_search($groupname, $groupname_lists);
                            $data['group_type'] = $groupVisibilityStatusId;
                            $sectionId = $program_group_model->saveProgramGroup($data);
                            $data[$sectionId]['selected'][] = $aaid;
                            $groupname_lists[$sectionId] = $groupname;
                        } else {
                            $temp = array_flip($groupname_lists);
                            $data[$temp[$groupname]]['selected'][] = $aaid;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($totalmismatch === 2) {
                        $errors['bothmismatch'] = $messages['bothmismatch'];
                    }
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                        $errors_data[] = [$key + 2, $error];
                    }
                }
                $groupSectionPreviousName = $groupname;
            }
            $programAASectionModelForSectionUsers = new ProgramSectionUser();
            $programAASectionModelForSectionUsers->saveProgramGroupUsers($data);
        });
```

$rules

```
array:7 [
  "aasectionname.required" => "501 – AA section does not exist"
  "aaid" => "numeric|exists:users,id|in:28,29,32,33,25,24,27|aaidinstitutionmismatch:42"
  "institutionid" => "numeric|in:42"
  "username" => "exists:users,UserName|in:Kabeer,Ayaz,fddesaaweqq,fdawerascvdfc,haseeb,kamran,shahid|usernameinstitutionmismatch:42"
  "schoolid" => "numeric"
  "groupowner" => "in:externalstaff,rahat,uzma,sahar,haseebahmad,saimariaz,fredrick"
  "remove" => "in:0,1"
]
```

Comment: I think you want `$teacher_rostered_users_data` to be array right? Because you used `lists()`.

Comment: Do "dd($rules);" and paste the results

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo   kindly check the dd($rules) I have updated the question

Comment: @aldrin27 no I need $teacher_rostered_users_data to be string of values separated by commas because laravel validator 'in' requires a string rather than an array

Comment: @RazaChohan because if it's array then he will use `implode()` and insert that inside `$rules`

Comment: The rules look ok, could you paste the data that you validate? If data is ok as well, then the issue is not during validation but in what happens afterwards. Are you getting a filename and line number with your error?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo kindly check I have updated my questions with remaining validation code.

Comment: wow, you validate in a loop so it might be so that some rows validate correctly and then an error occurs. we'd need to identify the data for which you're getting the error. Could you do dd() before "$aaid = intval($inputs['aaid']);" and see if there are any rows for which validation works?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo thanks I have updated by composer using composer update and everything is running as smooth as silk, but I wonder why this was hapenning.